# AppendBlob anytime append Azure

Tags: azure

i am aware there is an appendblob on Azure that allows us to append blocks.

I have not been able to understand from the documentation that if it's possible to create an appendblob in one process. Then after a certain timespan say few minutes can i append to this blob? Can the timespan be days etc.?

My use case is as follows:
I am sending a 4MB chunk of data to server that should be written to Azure storage as appendblob.

Then in a few seconds the next blob will upload to the server at which point I want to append to the above created appendblob.

And the process should continue. The question about time is the time it will take for the blobs to get there cannot be determined and hence they are all separate processes. Similarly what happens if we upload the chunk after a few days.

The above assumes that with each chunk we upload all the information required such as IDs etc for appending.

Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and describe your scenario? From your question it is not clear as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. One follow up question - What kind of data are you sending? Is it simply text data where time order in which the data is sent does not really matter?

Comment: Data sent is file data, on client-side i am chunking a file, then sending each chunk. On server-side it should append in order so order is highly important. I have the chunk id and all so i know if/ when to append.

Comment: Thanks! Is this scenario possible: Chunk id "1" sent at say 1:00 PM and then chunk id "3" sent at 1:01 PM and finally chunk id "2" sent at 1:02 PM? Essentially can you receive chunks out of order?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. So append order would have to be 1,2,3 not 1,3,2

Comment: Can you please include this in the main question itself? I think it is an important consideration. Based on this information, I would not recommend using append blobs. Instead use block blobs. I will include detailed answer regarding how to do it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments, I don't think `Append` blob is the right solution for you because as the name suggests, content always gets appended (i.e. added to the end of the blob) in the order it is received by storage service.

My recommendation would be to use `Block` blobs and utilize `Put Block`, `Get Block List` and `Commit Block List` functionality to achieve this functionality.

To work with these, first you need to assign an id to your chunk. Chunk id should be based on the order in which you want them to be added to your blob. I would recommend assigning numeric values (0, 1, 2...) left-padded with zeros (so that get chunk ids of same length - a requirement for uploading blocks). So your chunk ids will be 000000, 000001, 000002,...,000010,...and so on.

To upload the chunk, you will use [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) API. The block id will be the chunk id. Once you have uploaded the chunk, you will need to call [`Get Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list). This will give a list of all the chunks that are already uploaded and saved in the blob. You will insert this chunk id in the last uploaded chunk, sort them (very important) and then call [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) to modify the blob.

Note: Since you didn't mention the programming language/SDK you're using, I provided links to the REST API documentation. All of these operations are already implemented in various storage SDKs so you just have to find appropriate method and call them instead of performing REST API operations.